# Understanding nested node behavior with subscribers

Tags: ros2, python, subscribe, rclpy, ros-iron

When I run `action info`, the action subscriber shown is a different node than the node I passed to the AclientClient constructor.  Why is this?  It's not what I would expect.

Details:

I'm using `ros2 launch` with a launch.py file that looks like:

```py
    node = Node(
        name="launch_node_name",
        ...
        executable='make_blah.py',
    )
    ...
```

make_blah.py contains:

```py
    class Blah(Node):
        def __init__(self, node_name):
            super().__init__(node_name)
            self._sequence_action = ActionClient(
                self,
                MoveGroupSequence,
                "/sequence_move_group",
            )
    
    def main():
       Blah('self_node_name')
...
```

I would expect that if I used `ros2 action info` to see who was subscribing to /sequence_move_group, it would show self_node_name, since "self" is passed in the ActionClient constructor.  Instead, it shows that "launch_node_name" is the subscriber.

Why?  Is it an issue with a node making another node?  Or ... ?